# Python SkPy get outgoing calls of Skype

Tags: python, skype

```
from getpass import getpass
from skpy import SkypeEventLoop
from skpy import SkypeCallMsg
from skpy import Skype

class MySkype(SkypeEventLoop):

    def onEvent(self, event):
        print('Проверка...')
        
        try:
            print(event.msg.content)
            if event.type == 'NewMessage':
                
                print(event.msg.content)
                check_for_call = event.msg.content[:6]
                if check_for_call == """{"cp":""":
                    print("Входящий звонок")
                
                
                
        except:
            pass
            
            
            
        
        


if __name__ == "__main__":
    sk = MySkype("email", 'password', autoAck=True)
    sk.subscribePresence() # Only if you need contact presence events.
    sk.loop()
```

That code uses event event.msg.content, and receives incoming calls of my Skype, but how I can't get outgoing calls, probably outgoing calls receive with another method, I looked in documentation SkPy was class "SkypeCallMsg", maybe it help?

Get outgoing calls from Skype in Python with SkPy

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to find an answer for the same question, but I think currently there's no solution for listening to outgoing Skype calls. You receive an event update only if someone accepts an outgoing call, not when you start it.